# Why does Azure Blob Storage return 201, but not upload?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

After much pain and suffering I was finally able to get a 2xx status code from the Azure Blog Storage API on an upload request. I am not sure why this is so difficult when to compared to AWS S3.

Here is the code that I am using to upload a voice recording:

```js
var blockId = btoa("Test");
$.ajax({
    url: `https://${app}.blob.core.windows.net/blob/test.mp3?comp=block&blockid=${blockId}&${sas}`,
    type: 'PUT',
    contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
    data: audio.audioBlob,
    processData: false,
    headers: {
        'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
        'x-ms-date': new Date().toGMTString(),
        'x-ms-version': '2020-02-10'
    }
});
```

[image: NetworkTab1]

[image: NetworkTab2]

I am not sure if it matters, but I am using the following Chrome command to bypass CORS from my local machine.

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

I did try to enable CORS in the Azure Portal by setting the following values, yet that did not work.

- AllowedOrigins: *
- AllowedMethods: GET,PUT
- AllowedHeaders: *
- ExposedHeaders: *
- MaxAgeInSeconds: 86400

I was so excited I got a 2xx status code that I jumped to the Azure Portal. Unfortunately my file was not there. I thought it may be asynchronous so I waited 10 minutes. The recording I sent was only 5 seconds long so I'm certain it would not take longer than that.

- I checked the Monitoring graphs in Azure, which all showed 0 data.
- I double checked the information in my request and the Shared Access Signature, which looked correct to me.

Do you know what's happening here?

Comment: Side note, I updated the CORS Config from the Azure Portal the same way again and now it's working. Not sure why it wasn't working yesterday...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you know what's happening here?

I noticed that you're doing a chunked upload. Essentially you're performing [`Put Block`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block) operation (instead of [`Put Blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob) operation). `201` status code essentially tells you that the block (chunk) you uploaded reached storage successfully.

What you would need to do next is call [`Put Block List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-list) operation by including ids of all the blocks you uploaded. This will tell Azure Storage to stitch those blocks together and save them as blob.

Comment: Do you know what I need to change to use Put Blob instead?

Comment: Please change your URL from `https://${app}.blob.core.windows.net/blob/test.mp3?comp=block&blockid=${blockId}&${sas}` to `https://${app}.blob.core.windows.net/blob/test.mp3?${sas}` and that should do the trick.

Comment: Your suggestion worked! I also downloaded the file from Azure Portal and played the audio back to me, which worked. Cheers! I really appreciate it.